# Is there a standard name for a crossed rectangle placeholder?

Tags: interface-design, page-layout

In DTP type applications, a rectangle with a pair of diagonal lines from corner to corner is used as a placeholder to signify blank space awaiting content, or not rendered.

Example:

[image: example image from from http://www.sketchpad.net/quark-excel-chart-4.htm]

Is there a name for this element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply known as a frame.

In InDesign you can create these with the Rectangular Frame Tool and in wireframing apps they are just called frames.

Comment: I would understand 'frame' to mean something more general (like a text frame). But this image searches seem to confirm this usage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In spanish is "marco contenedor": frame container or container frame.